# How do I link the Accelerate Framework to a c program in MacOs?

Tags: c, xcode, linker, accelerate

I just started with c development and I need to compile and link a program which uses the Accelerate Framework from Apple:
Simple example `accelerate.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>

double vectorvector_product(double * a, double * b, int dim){
    // This function returns in res the elementwiseproduct between a and b,
    // a and b must have the same dimension dim.
    return cblas_ddot(dim,a,1,b,1);
}

int main(){
        double a[4] = {1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0};
        double b[4] = {1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0};
        double res = vectorvector_product(a,b,4);
        printf("Res: %f",res);
}
```

I compiled it with clang:

```
>>> cc -Wall -g -c accelerate.c
```

And obtained a new file `accelerate.o`
What would I do now in order to properly link it?
All I know is that this `Accelerate` framework is located at `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework`

```
>>> ls /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework

Accelerate.tbd  Frameworks  Headers     Modules     Versions
```

p.s.: If I Run this program with Xcode it magically works, but I need to do it from the command line and I would like to know what I'm doing.

Comment: Sounds like you still need to link it, e.g. using 'ld'

Comment: Yes, that's what I asked. What would be the correct syntax and which arguments should I use?

Comment: There's some info here, but I'm not a mac user. Perhaps someone else can comment: https://macresearch.org/performance-tutorial-part-i-introducing-accelerate/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the correct way to link `Accelerate.h` is by passing `-framework Accelerate` as argument e.g.

```
>>> cc -framework Accelerate accelerate.c
```

will compile and link `accelerate.c` by generating an executable `a.out`.